# How to Draw a point in an image using given co-ordinate with python opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv

I have one image and one co-ordinate (X, Y). How to draw a point with this co-ordinate on the image. I want to use Python OpenCV.

Comment: Might want to start by doing some research -- say be reading through the [tutorials in OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) that cover all this. | Don't really understand people upvoting this -- to me this is an obvious case of "does not show any research effort".

Comment: @DanMašek I see your point, but to be fair, I don't think the OpenCV tutorial shows how to create an image from scratch in Python - even the very first few most basic ones which only show how to load an image of Messi, and then launch into `numpy` pretty much without any explanation of how you might do anything without `numpy` or how you might create an empty image if you don't want to edit Mr Messi...

Comment: Python and OpenCV are rather a lot of software to install for this... I presume you ultimately intend to do something more complicated?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah, I suppose there are gaps. The [numpy Quickstart tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) is another thing to grok IMHO. You can't really get around `numpy`, as `numpy.array` is used in the Python bindings to represent `cv::Mat` (e.g. images).

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for the link - I have always worked with OpenCV's C++ binding and am finding the NumPy + Python way of doing things a challenge myself since I know neither.

Comment: Maybe you can use OpenCV's `putText` for this purpose. [This](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) might help.

Answer (score 96):

You can use `cv2.circle()` function from OpenCV module:

```
image = cv.circle(image, centerOfCircle, radius, color, thickness)
```

Keep `radius` as `0` for plotting a single point and `thickness` as a negative number for a filled circle

```
import cv2
image = cv2.circle(image, (x,y), radius=0, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=-1)
```

Comment: simple and effective.

Comment: The circle function allows you to plot points of arbitrary sizes.  If you only want your point to be the size of a single pixel, it is more efficient to use [Mark Setchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49854795/12808884)

Comment: Is there a way I can use an array of coordinates and do the same thing? Instead of at one coordinate?

Answer (score 26):

I'm learning the Python bindings to OpenCV too. Here's one way:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cv2
import numpy as np

w=40
h=20
# Make empty black image
image=np.zeros((h,w,3),np.uint8)

# Fill left half with yellow
image[:,0:int(w/2)]=(0,255,255)

# Fill right half with blue
image[:,int(w/2):w]=(255,0,0)

# Create a named colour
red = [0,0,255]

# Change one pixel
image[10,5]=red

# Save
cv2.imwrite("result.png",image)
```

Here's the result - enlarged so you can see it.

[image]

---

Here's the very concise, but less fun, answer:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Make empty black image
image=np.zeros((20,40,3),np.uint8)

# Make one pixel red
image[10,5]=[0,0,255]

# Save
cv2.imwrite("result.png",image)
```

[image]

Comment: If you only only need to plot a point the size of a single pixel, this is most efficient.  If you want your point to be larger, use [Dhanashree Desai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60546030/12808884)

Comment: Also, if you use this method, you need to specify the coordinate with the y value first and then the x value.  This is because in numpy the first axis represents rows, and the second represents columns.

Comment: @LelandHepworth If you want your point to be larger, it is still more efficient to use my technique, just do `im[10:14, 5:9] = [0,0,255]`.

Comment: @LelandHepworth Also, I intentionally made the point at `[10,5]` so it is clear that it is further down than across to illustrate precisely the point that the row comes first

Comment: good points.  That will make a larger square and will still be very efficient